# How to declare two suppressLint in one place in Android?

Tags: android, suppress-warnings

Sometime we want to declare two or more suppresslints for one class or method, how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "SetJavaScriptEnabled" })
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment{
    ...
}
```